# Cifrado no seguro Android

Tags: android

Actualmente tengo mi app a la hora de subir a la playStore la advertencia de

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi clase es la siguiente

```
public class CryptoHandler {

    private String SecretKey = "DKDJXNSKDJD";

    private static CryptoHandler instance = null;

    public static CryptoHandler getInstance() {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new CryptoHandler();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public String encrypt(String message) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
            BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {

        byte[] srcBuff = message.getBytes("UTF8");
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new
                SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.substring(0,16).getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] dstBuff = ecipher.doFinal(srcBuff);
        return Base64.encodeToString(dstBuff, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }



    public String decrypt(String encrypted) {

        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new
                SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.substring(0,16).getBytes(), "AES");

        Cipher ecipher = null;
        try {
            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            ecipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] raw = Base64.decode(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] originalBytes = new byte[0];
        try {
            originalBytes = ecipher.doFinal(raw);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String original = null;
        try {
            original = new String(originalBytes, "UTF8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return original;
    }
}
```

Alguien me indica el error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje que se muestra :

**"Tu aplicación incluye patrones de cifrado criptográfico no seguros."**

en inglés se muestra este mensaje:

**"Your app contains unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns"**

Este mensaje se muestra debido a que hay valores que son usados para la encriptación pero que estos no están siendo encriptados, recuerda que estos valores pueden ser extraídos de tu aplicación y podría ser usados en otra o para "atacar" tu app.

Por ejemplo podemos ver que tienes un Secret Key que esta escrito directamente en el código, lo cual no es recomendable:

```
  private String SecretKey = "DKDJXNSKDJD";
```

Puedes realizar varias técnicas, por ejemplo agregar estos valores dentro del archivo `gradle.properties`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

registrarlos dentro de `build.gradle` :

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
         ...
         ...
         ....

        buildConfigField "String", "MY_API_KEY", "\"$MY_API_KEY\""
    }

}
```

De esta forma podrías acceder al valor que se construye al compilar tu aplicación:

```
String valorAPI = BuildConfig.MY_API_KEY
```

---

Otra forma es guardar el valor de tus llaves en tus preferencias pero encriptado, usando la nueva clase [EncryptedSharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences) que forma parte de AndroidX que puede ser usada desde API 23.

Agrega la dependencia:

```
implementation 'androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0-beta01'
```

Usa el siguiente método:

```
   public SharedPreferences getEncryptedSharedPreferences(Context context){
        String masterKeyAlias = null;
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;
        try {
            masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC);
            sharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
                    "secret_shared_prefs_file",
                    masterKeyAlias,
                    context,
                    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
                    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
            );
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sharedPreferences;
    }
```

Este es un ejemplo de como guardar el valor:

```
getEncryptedSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit().putString("MY_API_KEY", "api243gdf$#GWDGSDG==").apply();
```

y como obtenerlo:

```
String valueAPI = getEncryptedSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("MY_API_KEY", "");
Log.d(TAG, "valor API Encriptado: " + valueAPI );
```

Comment: le echare un ojo probare y vengo a contarte jorge Gracias!

Comment: Ok Bruno, un saludo!